# Show that the largest interval of existence of the solution predicted by Picard's Theorem is $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let the $\operatorname{IVP}$ be given by:

$\dfrac{\operatorname{dy}}{\operatorname{dx}}=y^2+\cos^2 x;x>0;y(0)=0$

Show that the largest interval of existence of the solution predicted by Picard's Theorem is $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

*By **Picard's Existence and Uniqueness Theorem**;If $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$ and $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition on $D$ .If $R=\{|x-x_0|\leq a;|y-y_0|\leq b\}$ lies in $D$ and $M=\sup |f(x,y)|,h=\min\{a,\frac{b}{M}\}$. Then the $\operatorname{IVP}$ has a unique solution on the interval $|x-x_0|\leq h$.*

Obviously the Lipscitz Condition is satisfied here.But I can't find the rectangle which is needed to apply the theorem.How should I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case $x_0 = y_0 = 0$. For any $a > 0, b > 0$, the function
$f(x, y) = y^2 + \cos^2 x$ is defined and Lipschitz continous on
the rectangle $R=\{|x|\leq a, |y|\leq b\}$.

On this rectangle, $$|f(x, y)| \le |y|^2 + |\cos x|^2 \le b^2 + 1$$
with equality for $x = 0$ and $y = b$, so
the supremum is $M = b^2 + 1$ and therefore 
$$h= \min\{a,\frac{b}{b^2 + 1}\}$$

The Picard existence theorem states that the IVP has a (unique)
solution on the interval $[-h, h]$, or – if you restrict the problem
to $x \ge 0$ – on $[0, h]$.

The task is now to choose $a$ and $b$ such that $h$ becomes as
large as possible. From the AM-GM inequality is follows that
$$
 b = \sqrt{1 \cdot b^2} \le \frac{b^2 + 1}2 \Longrightarrow \frac{b}{b^2 + 1} \le \frac 12
$$
with equality for $b=1$.

It follows that $h \le \frac 12$ for *any* choice of $a, b$, and 
$h = \frac 12$ for $a = \frac 12, b = 1$. So
$h = \frac 12$  is the largest value that can be obtained by this
method.

Comment: Great answer +1

Comment: I been tying to figure out why I have a theorem in my text stating that the maximal intervall is never closed. This seems not to be the case here. You heard about such statements?

Comment: @user1: This question is about the *"largest interval ... predicted by Picard's Theorem,"* not about the maximal interval in which the solution actually exists.

Comment: oh,  I thought thats what that meant. Regardsless, the intervall that we obtain via global existance on rectangles is never maximal?

Comment: @user1: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Picard's theorem states that a solution exists on some (closed) interval. That does not exclude that a solution actually exists on a larger interval.

Comment: How do you know a priori that $|y|\leq b$ ? Couldn't y be unbounded in the region defined by $|x|\leq a$?

Comment: @plebmatician: $M$ is determined as the maximum of $|F(x, y)|$ on the rectangle $|x| \le a$, $|y| \le b$, and $h$ is computed as $\min(a, b/M)$. *Picard's theorem* then guarantees that a solution exists on the interval $[-h, h]$. – Roughly speaking, the upper bound $M$ is an upper bound for the derivative of $y$ and ensures that $y$ can not “explode” in that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
You could choose $M = b^2 + 1$. Then, try to find $a,b$ which maximizes $h = \min\{a, b/(b^2+1)\}$.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo!