# Improving choice of $\delta$ in Picards Iteration given a system of ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> For the first order system
>   $$x_1' = x_2, \hspace{1cm} x_2' = -\sin(x_1) - x_2|x_2| + \cos(t),$$
>   show that the right-hand side satisifies a Lipschitz condition in the domain $|x| \leq \beta$ for $|t| \leq \alpha$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary but finite numbers. Use Picard Iteration to deduce that the initial-value problem
>   $$x_1(0)=0, \hspace{1cm} x_2(0)=0$$
>   has a unique solution for $|t|\leq\delta$, and obtain an estimate for $\delta$. By allowing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be as large as possible, attempt to improve your estimate of $\delta$.

I am confused on how to estimate $\delta$, and consequently how to improve my choice of $\delta$. Anyway, my work up until that point is:

First we will show that the right hand side satisifies a Lipschitz condition on the specified domain. We have that $x_1$ satisifies the Lipschitz condition since 
$$x_1' = x_2 \leq |x| \leq \beta,$$
so that its derivative is bounded. Moreover, $x_2$ satisifies the Lipschitz condition since
$$x_2' = -\sin(x_1) - x_2|x_2| + \cos(t) \leq 2 + x_2|x_2| \leq 2 + |x|^2 \leq 2 + \beta^2$$
so we see that $x_2'$ is bounded as well, implying that it is Lipschitz. Now by Picard's Iterations since $D:=|x-0| \leq \beta$ and $I:=|t-0| \leq \alpha$ for some $\alpha,\beta>0$ satisfy the Lipschitz condition with some $L>0$, we have that the IVP:
$$\begin{cases} x'(t) &= f(x,t) \\ x_1(0) &= 0 \\ x_2(0) &=0 \end{cases}$$
has a unqiue solution on $|t| \leq \delta$, where 
$$\delta := \min\left\{\alpha, \dfrac{\beta}{M}\right\} \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} M:=\max_{D\times I} \|\ f(x,t) \|\ .$$
An estimate for $\delta$ would clearly be either $\alpha$ or $\beta/M$ by how $\delta$ is defined, but even if that is the estimate we're looking for, how would I improve that $\delta$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ getting larger.

Comment: It is not $x_1$ and $x_2$ which need to satisfy a Lipschitz-condition, but the right-handed side $f$ (but your proof for $x_2'$ is indeed enough for the first component of $f$).

Comment: Oh, so for the second component of $f$, would I differentiate the $-\sin(x_1) - x_2|x_2| + \cos(t)$ with respect to $x_2$? If so I get, $\dfrac{-2x_2^2}{|x_2|} \leq 2x_2 \leq 2|x| \leq 2\beta$ to get Lipschitz condition in the second component. Or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: No, that's not correct (my first comment was probably also misleading). $f$ satisfying a Lipschitz condition means that there exists a constant $L(\alpha, \beta)$ (depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$) such that for $|t| \leq \alpha$ and $||x||, ||y|| \leq \beta$: $||f(t,x) - f(t,y)|| \leq L(\alpha, \beta) ||x - y||$. It suffices to consider $f_1$ and $f_2$ and since $f_1(t,x) = x_2$ you clearly already have $|f_1(t, x) - f_2(t, y)| = |x_2-y_2| \leq ||x - y||$. For $f_2$ you need to find something similar but differentiating with respect to one variable won't do it.

Comment: Once you've got that, this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567467/show-that-the-largest-interval-of-existence-of-the-solution-predicted-by-picard?rq=1) might give you an idea on how to optimize $\delta$

Comment: So, let $Q:=\max(|y_2|,|x_2|)$ and then we have: $\|\ f(t,x) - f(t,y) \|| = \|\ (-\sin(x_1) - x_2|x_2| + \cos(t)) - (-\sin(y_1) - y_2|y_2| + \cos(t)) \|\ = \|\ (-\sin(x_1) - x_2|x_2| + \sin(y_1) + y_2|y_2| \|\ \leq \|\ 2 - x_2|x_2| + y_2|y_2| \|\ \leq \|\ 2 + Q(y_2 - x_2) \|\ \leq 2 + Q \|\ y_2 - x_2 \|\ \leq 2 + Q \|\ x - y \|\ $. Probably more long-winded than it needed to be, but will that suffice?

Comment: Replace $f$ with $f_2$, typo. Won't let me edit for some reason. :/

Comment: No, it doesn't suffice as **2** + ... $Q ||x-y||$ is not a Lipschitz condition. So you need to do this differently. Also on a smaller note, you're probably aware of this, you should not write 2 inside the norm.